# Fix for Google-served ads on screens with replicated content

Tags: admob, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have created an app based on ChatGPT OpenAI. I use their API to work as a chatbot.
I had Google ads on my app working normally, but recently the ads has been restricted due a "Google-served ads on screens with replicated content" issue.

My guess is that google is considering chat gpt answers as replicated content.

Is there a way to solve this or I have to accept that my app can't use google ads anymore?

I already removed banners on chat, but the issue persists.

Comment: Same happened with me too for my blog website. They have disabled my adsense account by giving the same excuse mentioned by you! :-( 
Did they disabled your account too? or you've just got the policy violation warning ?

Comment: Did you find a trustworthy information regarding this policy violation for this kind of apps?

Comment: Same bro. My app has something todo with AI text generation too and got ads restricted. It's seems like they are blocked every app with AI, especially the text generation one. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

This is the new copyright infrigments policy I belive. So if they think you are using others content, your app will stop serving admob ads. Most of the time, their algorithm mistaken what is really a copyright infrigments, so we are under a new kind of problem now.